# How do you reference multiple lookups from the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, alias

This is my first post, but I've been reading here for ages taking in a lot of great information.

Please bear with me as I try to explain my predicament. I wasn't even sure how to label my question, since I don't really know the terminology for what I'm trying to do. I'm a beginner of PHP/MySQL (this will become painfully obvious when you see my question), but I'm eager to learn.

Anyway, here goes:

I have two tables, named `Games` and `Teams`.

```
mysql> describe games;

+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| homeTeam  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| awayTeam  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| homeScore | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| awayScore | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| homeOdds  | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| drawOdds  | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| awayOdds  | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gameDate  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
mysql> describe teams;

+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| team  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like the fields `Games.homeTeam` and `Games.awayTeam` to do a lookup for their values in the `Teams.id` and `Teams.team` fields. Basically `Games.homeTeam` should find its equivalent in `Teams.id`. Simple enough. However, I would like both `Games.homeTeam` and `Games.awayTeam` to look in the `Teams` table within the same SQL statement.

I figured maybe something like this would work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Games g, Teams ht, Teams at where g.homeTeam = ht.id AND g.awayTeam = at.id ORDER BY g.gameDate") or die(mysql_error());
```

and then to pick the rows up:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "Home Team: " . $row['ht.team'];}
```

That's a no go, as I get a mysql error saying there's no index named `ht.team`.

I hope it's fairly clear what I'm trying to achieve here. How should I go about this? I assume I have to use aliases of some sort, but I can't wrap my head around as to what the SQL statement should look like to accomplish what I want.

Comment: to clarify what your exact problem is, $row['ht.team'] should be $row['team'] ... PHP is complaining that the key you passed, "ht.team" doesn't exist within the array. if you want to better see what mysql_fetch_array() returns, do a print_r($row); .. from there you'll see that @Michael Berkowski 's answer is a great fix to your dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `SELECT *` with join queries! Always be explicit about the columns you need in your `SELECT` list, and supply column aliases:

```
SELECT 
  /* Only select the columns you actually need, and 
   * supply aliases to those with similar names
   */
  ht.team AS ht_team,
  ht.id AS ht_id,
  at.team AS at_team,
  at.id AS at_id
  g.homeScore,
  g.awayScore,
  g.homeOdds,
  g.drawOdds,
  g.awayOdds,
  g.gameDate
FROM 
  Games g, 
  Teams ht, 
  Teams at 
where g.homeTeam = ht.id AND g.awayTeam = at.id 
ORDER BY g.gameDate
```

In your PHP, access them via their aliases, for example:

```
echo "Home Team: {$row['ht_team']}";
```

By the way, although your method of implicit (comma-separated tables and conditions in the `WHERE` clause) joins will work, using explicit joining is often recommended. It is a newer syntax, and will allow easier expansion into `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` when the need arises:

```
SELECT 
  ht.team AS ht_team,
  ht.id AS ht_id,
  at.team AS at_team,
  at.id AS at_id
  g.homeScore,
  g.awayScore,
  g.homeOdds,
  g.drawOdds,
  g.awayOdds,
  g.gameDate
FROM 
  /* Explicit JOIN syntax */
  Games g, 
  JOIN Teams ht ON g.homeTeam = ht.id 
  JOIN Teams at ON g.awayTeam = at.id 
ORDER BY g.gameDate
```

Comment: Simply awesome explanation! Lightning fast as well! Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is 
you give an alias to the table only , not to the column
 if there is not a column in Games table with the name team 
you can call it in your loop with only

$row['team'];

However if both of table have the same name column like team
so you should do this .
  `select ht.team as htTeam , g.team as gTeam`  from Teams ht inner join 
Games on ht.Id = .....

Then you can reach each team term with

```
$row['htTeam']
and $row['gTeam'];
```

and I think get used to decide a prefix for tables and the their columns